# How to create a readonly token, that validates some values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, encryption, cryptography

So I want to create a dynamic image resizer and want to protect it.

Let's say I get request like

```
/SomeID/400x300/{MyToken}.jpg
```

`{MyToken}` should only be valid for width `400`, height `300`, extension `jpg` and ID `SomeID`. This token should not be editable by the client, so I can prevent a DOS attac (Requesting thousand of combinations).

With not editable I mean, the client is not able to change the token to something else, that would be valid for other parameters.

If I recall correctly, ASP.NET Formauthentifcation has a algorythm to generate a readonly token. I am searching for something like this.

How does the Formauthentifaction work? How is the principe called? I am stuck at google, because I am not sure what are the right keywords.

What I could do, is a HtmlHelper, which does a `File.Exists()` and generates the image if the file does not exist. But since IO is expensive, I would want to get the file on the request, and catch a `FileNotFoundException` by generating the image, if the token is valid.

Comment: Minimize storage : use encryption/hashing to generate the token.
Minimize CPU usage : just create a GUID for each resource and store the GUID-resource relationship in a table.

Comment: The problem I have with encryption is, what is if somebodys calculates the key? With hashing the salt? Is there something that is more dynamic @Martheen

Comment: [AES](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks) seems safe enough against known plaintext attack. I don't know what can be more dynamic than storing a secret key/salt in the server and encrypt/hash it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the Formauthentifaction work? How is the principe called?

The type of encryption that Forms Authentication uses depends on the config, eg:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="..." 
                decryptionKey="..." 
                validation="SHA1"
                decryption="AES" />
```

It defaults to SHA1, which uses the HMACSHA1 algorithm.

To generate a token simply encrypt the ID, Size & File Extension, this is the most famous question on here with examples of encryption:
[Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)

Comment: Interessting, thank you. I think I generate a key every app pool recycle then. And I need to rethink the default security of Formsauthentification then... But that is another topic.

Comment: See jbtules answer where he generates the salt, that's the dynamic goodness you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/495455